Is DateTime.Now inconsistent over time?
My Application logs Telegrams via UART from a Bus. For each Telegram I add an Timestamp with DateTime.Now at reception. Now I have the phenomena, that sometimes the next telegrams timestamp is up to 100ms lower than the previous ones. This is so confusing.
How does this happen? How can I prevent it?
Heres my code:
private SerialPort port;

public void RegisterReceive()
        {
            ...
            port.DiscardOutBuffer();
            port.DiscardInBuffer();
            port.DataReceived += OnReceive;
            ....
        }

public static Mutex mutexReceivingCom = new Mutex();
        void OnReceive(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs args)
        {
            SerialPort port = sender as SerialPort;

            mutexReceivingCom.WaitOne();   // Wait until it is safe to enter. 

            if (data.AppIsRunning)
            {
                Byte by;
                try
                {
                    while (port.BytesToRead > 0)
                    {
                        by = (Byte)port.ReadByte();
                        mainWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                        {
                            General_HandleTelegram.Add_HandleTeleData_ByteToUartInBuffer(by);
                        });
                    }


                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("SerialPort OnReceive Exception: " + ex.ToString());
                    //put other, more interesting error handling here.
                }
            }

            mutexReceivingCom.ReleaseMutex();    // Release the Mutex.

            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(handleReceivedBytes);
        }

private void handleReceivedBytes(object state)
        {
            mutexReceivingCom.WaitOne();   // Wait until it is safe to enter. 

            if (data.AppIsRunning)
            {
                try
                {
                    BusAnswerOrCyclic_Handling tempPack = null;

                    if (port.IsOpen)
                    {
                        tempPack = ReceiveTelegram(LastRecTelegramm, this);

                        while (tempPack != null)
                        {
                            mainWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                            {
                                if (tempPack != null)
                                    tempPack.ProcessBusTelegram();
                            });

                            if (tempPack != null)
                            {
                                LastRecTelegramm = tempPack;
                            }

                            if (port.IsOpen)
                            {
                                tempPack = ReceiveTelegram(LastRecTelegramm, this);
                            }
                            else
                                break;
                        }

                    }

                    CheckIfBufferCanBeReset();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Error ComPort.cs handleReceivedBytes: " + ex.Message);
                }

            }

            mutexReceivingCom.ReleaseMutex();    // Release the Mutex.
        }



and then
public BusAnswerOrCyclic_Handling ReceiveTelegram(BusAnswerOrCyclic_Handling parLastSendBusTelegram, ComPort comPort)
        {
...
pack= new BusAnswerOrCyclic_Handling(recState, CmdToAssignToReceivedTele, LastSendBusTelegram, fetchedByteList.ToArray(), Generic_HandleTelegrams.mainWindow, comPort, -1, ucTelTyp == enTelTyp.SynLine, true);
....

return pack;
        }


public BusAnswerOrCyclic_Handling(enRecStates recState, BusTelegram_Command command, BusAnswerOrCyclic_Handling LastBusTelegram, byte[] bytes, MainWindow mainWindow, 
            ComPort comPort, short iMasterByteCountWithCRC, bool isSynLine, bool isFullyReceived)
        {
            DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
...
        }

while
public void ProcessBusTelegram()
        {
           // adds it to the datalog

        }

I don't get it how can the next telegrams timestamp be lower then the last ones?
see the code for what I tried

Use are using multithreading. Therefore, the order of execution of the tasks might be a bit random. This has most probably nothing to do with DataTime being inaccurate.

This sounds like it may be a continually running service.  I suggest you use DateTime.UtcNow to eliminate unexpected oddities due to DST transitiions.

DateTime.UtcNow doesn't really seem to help.

Threading. It's always threading.
You read DateTime.Now quite late, on the other side to a call to ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem.
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem isn't necessarily guaranteed to be ordered, and anyway you might have a situation where:

You queue message A then message B
Thread 1 picks up message A, then gets paused by the scheduler
Thread 2 picks up message B and runs to completion (reading DateTime.Now)
Thread 1 resumes, and reads DateTime.Now

If you care about the time when the bytes were received, then record DateTime.Now at the point that you read the bytes from the serial port, before you do any sort of thread dispatch (ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem, mainWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke, etc).

OK, but how do I fix this decently, without screwing everything up? The actual telegram logging seems to work fine aside the Timestamps...

Something related to this: I have an Answer-Function for my logging tool. The Answer function has issues with large delays for the Answer. I check if the received Telegrams have specific content and if that's the case I send an answer. I figure the Answer-Delay could be a lot smaller, if the ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem thingy wasn't so slow....

I kinda don't want to stay in the port.DataReceived / OnReceive function forever and halt my whole application for that time... Is there a way to shedule that stuff in a semi-high-prior task that gets worked through soonish?

Just capture DateTime.Now before you do the thread dispatch, as I said
